# Python List Comprehesion conversion

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I have a script like this

```
for key, Value in mydictionary.iteritems():
    if 'Mammal' in Value[1]: 
    #because the value is a list of 2 items and I want to get at the second one
        Value[1] = Value[1].strip('Mammal')
```

This code effectively removes Mammal from the beginning of the second item in the Value list. Now I want to make this nicer python looking with list comprehension so I came up with this but obviously is wrong.... Any help?

```
Value[1] = [Value[1].strip('Mammal') for Key, Value in mydictionary.iteritems() if 'Mammal' in Value[1] ]
```

Also, on the same lines, a list comprehension to list all the keys in this dictionary. I am having a hard time coming up with that one.

I came up with:

```
for key, Value in mydictionary.iteritems():
Templist.append(key)
```

but as a list comprehension I am thinking....but it doesn't work :(

```
alist = [key for Key, Value in mydictionary.iteritems()]
```

Comment: I recommend against CamelCase variable names and sticking to PEP8 ...

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `iterkeys` method? Actually iterating on a dictionary will iterate on its keys.

Comment: To get a list of keys you don't need a list comprehension. Use `myDict.keys()`

Comment: Do you really understand what do you want to do? If "This code effectively removes Mammal from the beginning of the second item in the Value list.", And the `Value` list is a value in a dictionary, WHY would you need list comprehension here? oO

Comment: I know what I want to do, its just that I am trying to learn both ways of doing it. Become more experienced as a python user. That is why I am asking, to be told by a pro so I can compare and learn.

Comment: `s.strip("Mammal")` doesn't do what you think it does.  For example, `"Malamman".strip("Mammal") == "n"`, and so you could strip more characters than you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydictionary = {
    1: [4, "ABC Mammal"],
    2: [8, "Mammal 123"],
    3: [15, "Bird (Not a Mammal)"]
}

mydictionary = {key: ([value[0], value[1].strip('Mammal')] if 'Mammal' in value[1] else value) for key, value in mydictionary.iteritems()}
print mydictionary
```

Output:

```
{1: [4, 'ABC '], 2: [8, ' 123'], 3: [15, 'Bird (Not a Mammal)']}
```

Although I wouldn't call this objectively "nicer looking", so the iterative method may be preferable.

Comment: You are actually creating a new dictionary - seem to be a wasteful approach.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much! I agree with you that the iterative way, especially for a newbee like me at least is more comprehensible whilst running code in my head. But I have to learn this anyways so thanks!

Comment: Also yes, it does create a new dictionary. The iterative way is at least for that matter alone better on the memory. But unless there is a way to do this without creating a new list, then this works for what I needed. How to make a list comprehension (I guess a dictionary comprehension) from a loop.

Answer (score 0):

**List comprehension creates a new list**

If you were able to use *strip()*, then *Value[1]* is a string - not a list

You may do 2nd part just with dictionary method *keys()* - both your attempts are redundant.

```
alist = mydictionary.keys()
```

Comment: you are right, Value[1] is a string, in a list called Value. But I don't think I ever said Value[1] is a list.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a list comprehension solely to create side effects. You can, but it is considered bad practice, and you should stick with the `for` loop.

Anyway, since you are working with a dictionary, you may be looking for a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
mydictionary = {'foo': ['unknown', 'Mammal is great'],
                'bar': ['something', 'dont touch me']}

mydictionary = {k: [a, b.replace('Mammal', '', 1)] for k, [a, b] in mydictionary.iteritems() if b.startswith('Mammal')}
```

Also note that using if you use dict comprehension, you create a new dictionary instead of replacing the values in your old one.

---

```
...
Value[1] = Value[1].strip('Mammal')
...
```

> This code effectively removes Mammal from the beginning of the second item in the Value list.

No, it does not. It replaces all occurrences of `M`, `a`, `m` and `l` from the beginning and the end of that item. Better use the `replace` method to replace the first occurrence of `Mammal` with an empty string.

---

```
alist = [key for Key, Value in mydictionary.iteritems()]
```

You have a typo here. It should read:

```
alist = [key for key, value in mydictionary.iteritems()]
```

or just

```
alist = mydictionary.keys()
```

Comment: @PierreGM Nice to have a typo in the word `typo` :-)

Comment: "since if your string does not contain Mammal, nothing would happen."  This isn't true -- `.strip()` removes the given characters, not the given string.

Comment: This updates my original dictionary without creating a new one and it also works; especially if you don't want to keep your old dictionary (why would you?...case by case i guess). THanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {'a':['Mammal','BC','CD'],
        'b':['AB','XY','YZ'],
        'c':['Mammal','GG','FD'],}

print [x for x,y in mydict.items() if y[0]=='Mammal']
```